# Live Change in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

```
 $('#<%=ddl.ClientID%>').live("change", function () { ShowLoadingPanel(); });
```

`ddl` is a dropdownlist. When the Selected Value changes in the dropdownlist, i want to display a Loading Panel. This code is working in all the browsers except IE. How to write the code so that it will support IE??

```
 $("#div1").delegate("change", function () {
     ShowLoadingPanel();
 });
```

Comment: `live` seems to me to be overkill for this. Does it work with `on`?

Comment: haven't .live() and .delegate() been deprecated and replaced with .on() ?

Comment: @ Constanta IE Version 10

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, `change` isn't part of `live`. It's also [deprecated as of jQuery 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/live/). You'll want to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$('#<%=ddl.ClientID%>').on("change", function () { ShowLoadingPanel(); });
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that also. I'm still having the issue. The content is loading through Ajax. Do you think, it should be the issue? Any Work around? Any help will be appreciated.....Thanks....

Comment: Are any errors being thrown in the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)? Have you checked to ensure that `<%=ddl.ClientID%>` is providing the same ID displayed when viewing the page's source?